# Gradle: process files inside a zip inside a tar

Tags: gradle

I have the following use case: I want to untar a tar file which contains a zip file. I then want to process files in the zip file (let's say I just want to filter out some file).

What I'm trying to do is something like:

```
task extractTar(type: Copy) {
   from(tarTree("../a.tgz")) {
     include '**/*.zip'
   }
   into "${buildDir}/tarOutput"
}

task unzipAndRezipZip(type: Zip, dependsOn: extractTar) {
  archiveFileName = "rezipped.zip"
  destinationDirectory
  from(fileTree("${buildDir}/tarOutput").find { it.name.endsWith("zip") }) {
      exclude '**/b.txt'
  }
}
```

I've spent many many hours on this and every way I try to do it, it fails some way or another.

#### Expected Behavior

I can use the output files from a CopyTask in my ZipTask.

#### Current Behavior

```
path may not be null or empty string. path='null'
```

or

```
Circular dependency between the following tasks:
:unzipAndRezipZip
\--- :unzipAndRezipZip (*)
```

#### Steps to Reproduce

I have made a repo which has three examples of different things I tried: https://github.com/viktornordling/gradle-unzip-zip-from-tar-issue and clearly shows the repro steps for each example.

(I also put this in https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/16413, but I'm not sure how much love it will get there. Cross posting here to see if I can get some traction.)

Update: I would prefer not to use `doLast` in the solution as I feel that should not be needed. Usage of `doLast` is explicitly discouraged in [the docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/common_caching_problems.html#custom_actions) and not mentioned in the [docs of CopyTask](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html).

Comment: I'm not seeing where it discourages doLast at that doc link, it seems to discourage doFirst and provides a doLast example as a better pattern instead. What am I missing.

Comment: OK fair, but I still feel like you shouldn't _need_ to use `doLast` for this to work, especially since the CopyTask docs never talk about `doLast`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In example-4 from your repo https://github.com/viktornordling/gradle-unzip-zip-from-tar-issue you state that it almost works, but fails when you run `clean unzipAndRezipZip` in one go, with the error message `Cannot expand ZIP...`:

```
task unzipAndRezipZip(type: Zip) {
  archiveFileName = "rezipped.zip"
  destinationDir(file("${buildDir}/zipOutput"))
  from(zipTree(tarTree("../a.tgz").find { it.name.endsWith("zip") })) {
    exclude '**/b.txt'
  }
}
```

You can fix that by changing the call to `from()` to a closure `from { }` to delay the execution of `zipTree`, i.e.:

```
task unzipAndRezipZip(type: Zip) {
  archiveFileName = "rezipped.zip"
  destinationDir(file("${buildDir}/zipOutput"))
  from { zipTree(tarTree("../a.tgz").find { it.name.endsWith("zip") }) } {
    exclude '**/b.txt'
  }
}
```

Comment: OK, that's nice and that works. Here, take your 150 points! :D

Comment: Though, I am still very curious why this is so hard to do if you break it up into two tasks. Any ideas @mcernak?

Comment: The same thing applies when you have two tasks. Change the content of `from` to a closure, i.e. replace line `from(fileTree("${buildDir}/tarOutput").find { it.name.endsWith("zip") }) {` with `from{fileTree("${buildDir}/tarOutput").find { it.name.endsWith("zip") }} {`, so that the execution of `fileTree` is delayed and runs only after the other task `extractTar` has had a chance to extract the files from `a.tgz`

Comment: Thanks again @mcernak! While that works, it turns out I accidentally over simplified the example here in my quest to make a minimal repro. We need to `zipTree` the zip file in order to filter out b.txt. If I simply add `zipTree` around the `fileTree`, I again get the same errors (even with the closure). I added an `example-5` to show this. Can you crack this?

Comment: Hey @mcernak, you still there? :)

Comment: I'm starting to think that not even @mcernak can crack this! :thinkingface :)